# How to scp from MacOSX to Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I tried the command

```
scp -i /Users/nehagupta/Desktop/aaa.pem /Users/nehagupta/Desktop/file.fa ubuntu@ec2-107-20-102-12.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/mnt/abc/
```

but it gives me

> Warning: Identity file /Users/nehagupta/Desktop/matt.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
>   Permission denied (publickey).
>   lost connection

Answer (score 0):

Are you on your local machine or on EC2?

You should try the above command from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can Upload more as one file with this command:

scp -P **SSH_PORT** /Users/blubb/keys/sys/cert.pem /Users/blubb/keys/sys/pk.pem yournamenotrootaccount@yourserver:/home/blubb

make sure your security group has the right to connect from your local adress to your server via ssh!